# Navigate with object

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

According to this [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.navigate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the `NavigationServe.Navigate` methods must have an overload to accept an object as augment, In Visual Studio 2013, and having .Net 4.5.1 installed, the IDE can't find the overload and it forces me to use a URI. Is there anything wrong with my Visual Studio or it has been discontinued, etc.

```
this.NavigationService.Navigate(new ShowRoom("", ""));
// The best overload for navigation..... has some invalid arguments
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice how the version selector on the MSDN article you pointed to is set to `.NET Framework 4.5`. This overload does not apply to Windows Phone 8 (for which the version would be `Silverlight`).

Here is the NavigationService API definition for Windows Phone 8: [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice(v=vs.95).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

You will see that there is only one `Navigate` definition, taking in a `Uri`. You would use it like this:

```
this.NavigationService.Navigate("/ShowRoom.xaml?parameter1=value1");
```

Comment: Thank you Mleroy, unfortunately I don't know anything about silverlight, maybe that's why I confused the two Navigate methods.